# How to fill background image in Vue JS + Bootstrap app with dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

So I've been trying to set my apps background but when I render dynamic content using v-for,  this white block appears to above my app background. Has anyone run into this, I've been trying to solve it for hours. Seems like my background is fully stretching. Thanks

[image: eu]

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row my-row mt-5">
        <div v-for="n in 20" :key="n" class="col-10 col-lg-3 col-md-5 my-col mt-5 mt-lg-0">
          <img class="img" src="../assets/vinyl.png" alt="Store Images" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
#app{
  background: url("./assets/background.svg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```
.container{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? do you see something relevant when inspecting `.container` with the browser's dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving height, you can use `min-height: 100vh;`

```css
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#app {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 100px;
}

.long{
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
 <div id="app">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="long">
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z01wbdmq/

Answer (score 0):

```
body {   
  background: url("./assets/background.svg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
   }
```

Looks like changing the body did the trick